# get the duplicated records in Django queryset

Tags: django

I want to get the duplicated of ticket field in table FollowUp (Django)

```
class FollowUp(models.Model):
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticket, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('Ticket'))
    comment = models.TextField(_('Comment'), blank=True,null=True)


class Ticket(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_('Title'), max_length=200)

followups = FollowUp.objects.values('ticket').annotate(ticket_count=Count('ticket')).filter(ticket_count__gt=1)
print(followups)
```

but I get empty Queryset although I have duplicated records:

> <QuerySet []>

when printing FollowUp.objects.values('ticket').annotate(ticket_count=Count('ticket')) I get:

> <QuerySet [{'ticket': 57, 'ticket_count': 1}, {'ticket': 58, 'ticket_count': 1}, {'ticket': 59, 'ticket_count': 1}, {'ticket': 59, 'ticket_count': 1}, {'ticket': 59, 'ticket_count': 1}, {'ticket': 59, 'ticket_count': 1}, {'ticket': 60, 'ticket_count': 1}, {'ticket': 60, 'ticket_count': 1}, {'ticket': 61, 'ticket_count': 1}, {'ticket': 61, 'ticket_count': 1}, {'ticket': 61, 'ticket_count': 1}, {'ticket': 62, 'ticket_count': 1}]>

I expect to get:

> <QuerySet [{'ticket': 57, 'ticket_count': 1}, {'ticket': 58, 'ticket_count': 1}, {'ticket': 59, 'ticket_count': 4}, {'ticket': 60, 'ticket_count': 2}, {'ticket': 61, 'ticket_count': 3}, {'ticket': 62, 'ticket_count': 1}]>

Comment: What is `ticket`? A `ForeignKey`, can you share (relevant parts) of your `FollowUp` and `Ticket` model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to force a `GROUP BY`. You can do this with a `.order_by(…)` clause, so:

```
from django.db.models import Count

followups = FollowUp.objects.values('ticket').annotate(
    ticket_count=Count('ticket')
).order_by('ticket').filter(
    ticket_count__gt=1
)
print(followups)
```

That being said, if `ticket` is a `ForeignKey`, you better query the `Ticket` object itself, something like:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Ticket.objects.prefetch_related('followup_set').annotate(
    followups=Count('followup')
).filter(followups__gt=1)
```